# Validation where to organize in web app for more efficient way

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

I'm thinking about validation of my web application. Here is to approaches.
1) Make validation with Spring Validator implement interface
2)Use JSR-303 on  domain model.

First approach looks more nicer  like I can use messages to render errors on any languages and can do more complex logic. But hibernate docs shows that JSR-303 more preferable as for hibernate, I'm thinking I already identified my entity with annotation mapping and put more for validation JSR 303 it won't be much?  Maybe I should do it on both if it possible.

What you suggest? Thank you

Comment: Why not using both? The one goes well with the other as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think that web (or input) validation is very, different from persistence validation. Often they will be the same, but often they won't, unless your app only takes data and puts in a DB without doing anything else apart from validation.

If you mingle your persistence and input validation, your domain model will suffer as you'll try to make it a mix of presentation+domain model, and changes in one will affect the other (bye, bye locality).

Mixing the validations might be ok on a very simple application or if you're building a "naked objects" solution (in which case the input MUST be the domain).

Comment: yes. the problem is before i use validation on model data when i did sql script for create my model data schema and used spring validation as validation for my app for input, messages etc. Now I decide that I want create my schema on start up by hibernate.

Comment: Creating a schema from hibernate is also usually a bad idea for the following reasons: 1) You still need update scripts (don't let hibernate upgrade a database schema!). 2) usually databases provide a lot more flexibility in crating a schema, e.g. you can create different types of indexes, or store data in different partitions of the database, etc. As I mentioned before, this is ok if the app you're building is small and not intended for production use.

Comment: Thank you. I was also thinking about this.