# Should I rely on database for Hibernate attributes validation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, bean-validation

JEE6 tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) suggests JSR-303 / Bean Validation should be used for validating input - or at least that's my interpretation of it.

Nevertheless, some Bean Validation annotations, such as @NotNull may not useful at an interface validation level, but rather at pre-persistence level.

For example, consider the following entity:

```
public class Registry {

    @NotNull
    String userName;

    @NotNull
    Date createdAt;
}
```

In this case, there's a form on which userName is filled by the user himself. But I don't want the user to know about the date this registry was created. I want my backend to set it with server's current date.

So, I'd normally bind this object to a form on a page, and use @Valid to perform JSR-303 validation. But the thing is: I don't "createdAt" to be validated by Bean Validation, I want it to be validated only when the entity is going to be persisted by Hibernate. But, with Bean Validation, both attributes get validated on form request.

How to address this? Would JSR-303 supposed to work in such scenario? Should I rely on database nullable field validation for "createdAt" attribute?

This post is pretty much about the same issue, but I haven't found any answers there either: [Validation where to organize in web app for more efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497302/validation-where-to-organize-in-web-app-for-more-efficient-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your constraints to different [validation groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups) and validate one group upon form submittal (e.g. the default group) and the other one upon pre-persist (e.g. a validation group `PrePersist`:

```
@interface PrePersist {}

public class Registry {

    @NotNull
    String userName;

    @NotNull(groups = PrePersist.class)
    Date createdAt;
}
```

Specify the group to be used during pre-persist like this in your persistence.xml:

```
<persistence ...>
    <persistence-unit ...>
        ...
        <properties>
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist" 
                value="com.example.PrePersist"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```